# How to find the maximum possible value of $\big| (z_1-z_2)^2+(1-z_1)(1-z_2) \big|$ given that $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to find the maximum possible value of $\big| (z_1-z_2)^2+(1-z_1)(1-z_2) \big|$   given that $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$ ?

I cannot think of any easy method to do it. Any suggestion?

P.S: Avoid using multivariable calculus.

Comment: As hinted in my comment to that [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149243/how-to-find-the-maximum-and-minimum-value-of-leftz-1-z-22-z-2-z-32), it could probably be worked out the hard way, by writing everything in polar form then using some trig (since everything can be expressed in terms of half-angles of the two arguments), but it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Isn't it $6$ when $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = -i$

Comment: @user399601 Correct. I don't know why Wolfram Alpha seems to give a wrong result.  (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+%7C(z1-z2)%5E2-(1-z1)(1-z2)%7C+given+%7Cz1%7C%3D%7Cz2%7C%3D1) is

Comment: @anonymous I had the sign wrong in my original comment. The inequality to prove has a $+$ not a $-$ between the two terms. As for WA, I believe it's assuming $z_{1,2}$ to be real numbers.

Comment: Taking into account the remark of @user399601, why don't you change the 4 into a 6 in your question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie How do we know if 6 is the correct maximum ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Or keep the $4$ but change the sign from $-$ to $+\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I made that change.

Comment: The reason I think this is duplicate
$$(z_1-z_2)+(z_2-z_3)+(z_3-z_1)=0$$

and
$$\left|(z_1-z_2)^2+(z_2-z_3)^2+(z_3-z_1)^2\right|=\\
\left|z_1^2-2z_1z_2+z_2^2+z_2^2-2z_2z_3+z_3^2+z_3^2-2z_3z_1+z_1^2\right|=\\
2\left|z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2-z_1z_2-z_2z_3-z_3z_1\right|=\\
2\left|z_1(z_1-z_2)+z_2(z_2-z_3)+z_3(z_3-z_1)\right|=\\
2\left|z_1(z_1-z_2)+z_2(z_2-z_3)+z_3(-(z_1-z_2)-(z_2-z_3))\right|=\\
2\left|(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)+(z_2-z_3)^2)\right|$$
and replace $z_1=1$