# Hlawka's inequality proof in $\mathbb{C}$ with integrals

Tags: inequality, terminology, absolute-value

Does anybody know a proof of Hlawka’s inequality using integrals?
You can find the inequality here
http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/Hlawka.shtml

Usually it’s tackled with the triangle inequality and some algebraic manipulation. I vaguely remember seeing a calculus based proof, but I don’t remember the details.

This is the inequality: a, b and c are complex numbers, prove
$|a| + |b| + |c| + |a+b+c| \geq |a+b| + |a+c| + |b+c|$

Comment: Perhaps it's just some version of the triangle inequality. Given three points $a,b,c,$ then we have that $|a-c|\le |a-b|+|b-c|.$

Comment: No, it much more complicated, there are 3 or 4 terms on one side.

Comment: Maybe Hlawka's inequality: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/Hlawka.shtml

Comment: That’s exactly what I thought, thanks. Has anyone seen a proof with integrals? Or otherwise seen the technique where elementary inequalities are solved by turning them into integrals?

Comment: @user623949, Edit your question to clarify exactly what you want (a proof with integrals for Hlawka's inequality which is ...). As it stands it might soon be closed for a lack of details and clarity.

Comment: Done, thank you

Comment: @user623949, it's still (very) unclear and therefore the question was closed. The question should be self-contained (many people won't know what Hlawka's inequality is) and show your effort. I would recommend you to edit the question again, add the precise statement of Hlawka's inequality, context (what are you interested about it, what proof you already know) and what you have tried towards your proof. After you do this, let me know here and I will nominate the question for reopening then.

Comment: Ok, I tried again

Comment: @user623949, It's ok now. It will soon be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noam D. Elkies posted one solution for another inequality involving absolute values
by using integral: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167741

I tried to write down the details and put it here.

First, let us prove the inequality for real numbers $a, b, c$. 
WLOG, assume that $a + b \ge 0$ and $a + c \ge 0$.
If $b + c\ge 0$, then $\mathrm{RHS} = a + b + c + (a+b+c)$.
If $b + c < 0$, then $\mathrm{RHS} = a + (-b) + (-c) + (a+b+c)$.
The desired result follows.

Second, let us prove the inequality for complex numbers $a, b, c$.
From the inequality for real number $a, b, c$, by using the identity
$$|z| = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi} |\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} z)| \mathrm{d} \theta, \tag{1}$$
the desired result follows (note: $\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} z)$ is real).

*Proof of the identity in (1)*: Let $z = r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{\phi}}$ with $r \ge 0$.
We have
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi} |\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} z)| \mathrm{d} \theta
= \frac{1}{4} r \int_0^{2\pi} |\cos (\theta + \phi)| \mathrm{d} \theta
= \frac{1}{4} r \cdot 2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x \mathrm{d} x = r.$$

$\phantom{2}$

Remark: I remember another example of using integral to prove inequality involving absolute values (many years ago).

Let $z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n$ be complex numbers with $|z_1|+|z_2|+\cdots +|z_n|=1$. Denote $[1..n] = \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.
Prove that 
$$\max_{J \subseteq [1..n]} \Big|\sum_{i\in J} z_i\Big| \ge \frac{1}{\pi}.$$

*Proof*: Consider
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^n \max\{\mathrm{Re}(z_ke^{-\mathrm{i} t}), 0\} \mathrm{d} t
= \sum_{k=1}^n |z_k| \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x \mathrm{d} x = \sum_{k=1}^n 2|z_k| = 2.
\end{align}
Thus, there exists $t_0 \in [0, 2\pi]$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \max\{\mathrm{Re}(z_ke^{-\mathrm{i} t_0}), 0\} \cdot 2\pi \ge 2. \tag{2}$$
Let $S = \{k \in [1..n] : \ \mathrm{Re}(z_ke^{-\mathrm{i} t_0}) > 0\}$. From (2), we have
$\sum_{k \in S} \mathrm{Re}(z_ke^{-\mathrm{i} t_0}) \ge \frac{1}{\pi}$ or
$$\mathrm{Re} \Big(e^{-\mathrm{i} t_0} \sum_{k \in S} z_k\Big) \ge \frac{1}{\pi}. $$
Then, by using $|u| \ge \mathrm{Re}(u)$, we have
$$\Big|\sum_{k \in S} z_k\Big | \ge \frac{1}{\pi}.$$
We are done.