# n complex numbers inside a disk with center $A$ and radius 1

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math

Inside the disk with center $A(2,0)$ and a radius of $1$, a set of $n \geq 1$ points is considered, each having the respective affixes $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$. Show that

$
\left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i \right| \cdot \left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{z_i} \right| > \frac{3}{4} n^2.
$
source: RMG 2023

I have tried writing $z_k = a_k + b_k \cdot i$, where $ |z_k - 2|<1
 $ and then using the formula for the modulus of a complex number and it got me here

$\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k\right)^2} \cdot \sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{a_k^2 + b_k^2}\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{a_k^2 + b_k^2}\right)^2} > \frac{3}{4}n^2
$
How could I continue from here or what would be a better proof for it?

Comment: What is RMG?please share the full form. Thank you.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Romanian Mathematical Gazette

Comment: is it same as the Romanian maths magazine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$ \tag{1}
 \sum_{k=1}^n |z_k| \cdot  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{|z_k|} \ge n^2
$$
by the inequality between harmonic and arithmetic mean.

What we need next is a lower bound of $\left| \sum_{k=1}^n z_k \right|$ in terms of $\sum_{k=1}^n |z_k|$, and similarly for the sum of the reciprocals. This is where the restriction $|z_k - 2|<1$ comes into play: All $z_k$ in that disk lie in the sector
$$
 S = \{  z = r e^{i \phi} \mid r > 0, -\frac\pi 6 < \phi < \frac\pi 6\} \,. 
$$

[image]

For $z = x+iy \in S$ is
$$
|y| \le \tan(\frac \pi 6) \cdot x = \frac{x}{\sqrt 3}
$$
and therefore
$$
 |z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+ \frac{x^2}{3}} = \sqrt{\frac 4 3} \cdot x \, . 
$$
It follows that
$$ \tag{2}
\left| \sum_{k=1}^n z_k \right| \ge \operatorname{Re} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n z_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(z_k)
\ge \sqrt{\frac 3 4} \sum_{k=1}^n |z_k| \, .
$$
Also $z \in S \implies 1/z \in S$, so that
$$ \tag{3}
\left| \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k}  \right| \ge \sqrt{\frac 3 4} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{|z_k|}
$$
holds as well.

Combining the estimates $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ we get the desired inequality.

Comment: Could you please explain to me this part: $$
 S = \{  z = r e^{i \phi} \mid r > 0, -\frac\pi 6 < \phi < \frac\pi 6\} \,. 
$$ what does $ z = r e^{i \phi} $ mean. I have just started working with complex numbers and I’m not very familiar with those notations. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @math.enthusiast9: That are polar coordinates. $e^{i \phi} = r (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$, $r$ is the absolute value and $\phi$ the argument of $z$. $S$ is the sector of all complex numbers with an argument between $-\pi/6$ and $\pi/6$.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative proof.*

*Remark*: The question reminds me of 2014, CMO (Chinese Mathematical Olympiad), Problem 1:

> Given $r \in (0, 1)$ and complex numbers $z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n$ satisfying $|z_k - 1| \le r, k=1, 2, \cdots, n$, prove that
> $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right|\cdot \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k}\right| \ge n^2 (1 - r^2).$$

$\phantom{2}$

The same approach is used here.

Let $z_k = x_k + \mathrm{i}y_k, \forall k$.
Then $1 \le x_k \le 3, \forall k$
and $y_k^2 \le 1 - (x_k - 2)^2, \forall k$.

Using $|z| \ge |\mathrm{Re}(z)|$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \left|\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right|\cdot \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k}\right|
 &\ge \left|\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right)\right|\cdot \left|\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k}\right)\right|\\[6pt]
 &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)
 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{x_k^2 + y_k^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)
 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{x_k^2 + 1 - (x_k - 2)^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)
 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{4x_k - 3}\right)\\[6pt]
 &\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)
 \left(\frac{n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{4 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k - 3n}\right) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we use Jensen's inequality to obtain
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{4x_k - 3} \ge \frac{n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{4 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k - 3n}$ since $u\mapsto \frac{u}{4u - 3}$ is convex on $u \ge 1$.

Let $S = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \in [n, 3n]$. Using (1), we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right|\cdot \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k}\right| - \frac34 n^2
\ge S \cdot \frac{n S}{4S - 3n} - \frac34 n^2
= \frac{n(2S - 3n)^2}{4(4S - 3n)} \ge 0.$$
Moreover, clearly the equality can not occur.

We are done.